# Is it possiple to use "on" keyword in Graphql as a parameter name, and if not is there away to do it?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

I have this fragment

```
fragment fragBooking on Booking{
    at
    on
    on_date
    price
    passengers
}
```

and as you can see there's a parameter called "on" which is a date, but Graphql gives me an Error

```
Unsupported token `on`
```

is it possible to use it?